# Shadow panel missing from Render Properties

Tags: rendering, shadows

It's been a couple of days since I installed the latest version of Blender and in the *Render Properties* I cannot see the *Shadow Panel* in order to increase the shadows' quality.

[image]

I searched in the *Preferences* thinking it could have been disabled but I could not find it there either. Do you have any idea what's wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are in Render Engine > Cycles , switch to Eevee

Comment: Yes, I figured it out later but I still want to use Cycles as my Render Engine. Is there any chance I can improve my shadows quality?

Comment: it depends what you mean, actually as far as I know, contrary to Eevee, it all depends to your light sources

Comment: I agree, unfortunately. Thank you a lot by the way!